# PHP Static Binary - with inotify Extension

Tags: php, compilation, inotify

I recently found out how to build a standalone php binary ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173906/compile-php-into-static-binary)), which works great!

Is there a way to include the [inotify](http://php.net/manual/de/book.inotify.php) [extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/inotify) into this binary?

I dont find any documentations about building php with inotiy, only about extend php with the "pecl extension" inotify - may this is the problem, its a pecl extension and therefore not includable into the php binary?

is there another approach to deliver the binary with this inotify extension (except normal php installation)?

Target is, to deliver a php cli application, which is independent of the installed php version of the destiantion server (which works great till now, until we would need the inotify extension in php..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found [this](http://php.net/manual/de/install.pecl.static.php) pretty documentation, which solved my problem.
INotify (and all other modules) works with the single static binary, compiled (in debian 7) via:

`./configure --enable-static --enable-cli --enable-inotify --with-openssl --with-openssl-dir=/usr/bin`

complete progress:

- download /etxtract php711 source
- download /extract inotify module
- rename inotify folder to "inotify"
- mv inotify folder to {phpsrc}/ext/inotify
- change dir to {phpsrc}
- `rm configure`
- `./buildconf --force`
- `./configure --enable-static --enable-cli --enable-inotify --with-openssl --with-openssl-dir=/usr/bin`
- `make`
- have fun with the stand alone php cli binary located @ {phpsrc}/sapi/cli/php

The binary even works with other distributions (short tested in centos 6 and latest arch)